# Recursive self-join in HANA SQLSCRIPT procedure

Tags: graph, recursive-query, hana, self-join

According to academical literature 
http://pi3.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/~norman/HANA_SqlScript_BTW2013.pdf

HANA would support recursive calls on hierarchical tree as following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE browse_set_top_bt
(IN depth INTEGER, IN currDepth INTEGER, IN current tt_from_to, 
OUT hull tt_from_to)
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
READS SQL DATA AS
BEGIN 
relevant = SELECT Frm , To
FROM CustomerConnections
WHERE weight >=   2;
temp   = SELECT c.Frm , r.To 
FROM :current c, :relevant r
WHERE c.To = r.Frm ;
currDepth = currDepth + 1;
IF( currDepth < depth )
CALL browse_set_top_bt ( depth, currDepth, temp, temp2 )
hull = :temp UNION :temp2;
ELSE
hull = :temp;
END;
END;
```

Any further support in this eventual manner to browse a parent-child tree in a recursive self-join way is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but you mistook the academic test implementation of a query processing feature for a part of delivered standard product functionality.

SAP HANA does not support recursive queries as described in the paper.

What it does support are graph-oriented queries (maybe suitable for your use case here) and hierarchical queries.
I recommend checking the actual product [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/2.0.02/en-US) for details on both!